# Get parent item from blogpost viewmodel - Sitefinity

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-10

I need to get the parent (blog) item in the razor view from the viewmodel object for any given blog post.

I'm doing this in the standard List.BlogPostList.cshtml file.

More specifically, I need either the set URL or title. Since the controller is wrapped up in the resources for this application, I don't have direct access to it.

---

**Tried**

`item.ParentItem().DataItem.GetDefaultUrl()`

Got this in the error log:

Could not find a parent item property for the given item. This extension method should only be used for accessing a parent item of DynamicContent items.

---

**Tried**

`item.GetRelatedParentItems("Blog").ToString()`

Got this in the error log:

Type "Blog" cannot be resolved.

Looks like that's close, but I cannot guess as to the `parentItemsTypeName` magic string it wants, and of course the Sitefinity documentation is attrocious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Items)
{
       var parent = (item.DataItem as BlogPost).Parent;
       var parentTitle = parent.Title;
       var parentUrl = parent.UrlName;
}
```

Make sure to add the following using clauses as well:

```
@using Telerik.Sitefinity.Blogs.Model;
```

Comment: Getting null reference exception on `var parent = (item.DataItem as DynamicContent).SystemParentItem;` - I do have the @using clauses

Comment: `item.DataItem` is good, so it's either something within the casting or the .SystemParentItem DNE

Comment: It's not the casting, attempting to access SystemParentItem throws the error

Comment: After some testing, the casting of `item.DataItem` to DynamicContent is null

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked it. Updated the answer above

Comment: I love you please have my babies.